# Covering up an Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: linux, desktop

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I'm trying to modify an ubuntu 10.10 distro by hiding the entire desktop so that after the user boots it up all they see is a solid colour. The reason for this is that I am currently writing a glade application manager which will be the user's only interface with the OS and will sit on top of this background. I think I'm looking for a method to create a kiosk distro. I have looked and found no real good tutorials. I've not really messed with linux much in the past so if anyone any pointers/ideas it would be a real help.

Cheers in advance

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're not really ready for such a huge project...

Anyways, Ubuntu comes afaik with KDE or GNOME desktop environment. So if you don't need it, then don't launch it. Just start X11 with a solid background color. It really doesn't make sense to fire up KDE or GNOME and hide everything but a solid background color.

That's like "I want to have a seat and buy a jumbo jet and remove everything but one single seat".

Comment: Cheers, for the advice, but not for the sarcastic comment. I'm working on something I've not had to do before in my career therefore I come here to ask people who know more than me on this topic. if no one ever asked no one would ever learn.